# Unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$$

Tags: sql, postgresql, dbeaver, dollar-quoting

I'm trying to declare some variables using DBeaver and keep hitting this error.

```
Unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$$

 DO $$
 DECLARE A integer; B integer;

BEGIN   
END$$;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html and 
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DBeaver was the issue.  Switched to PGAdmin and no more problems.

Answer (score 5):

As of DBeaver 6, you can execute the script with ALT-X (on Windows), which does not attempt to do variable capture/interpolation involving dollar signs.

Comment: According to the icons in the editor, alt+x executes the whole script. This is the easier solution, but you can also highlight the entire query and execute the single statement and it won't give any errors.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax posted is fine. Your problem is that the client application or driver is mangling the query, probably because it doesn't understand dollar-quoting.

It might be trying to split it into separate statements on semicolons, running:

- `DO $$ DECLARE A integer;`
- `B integer;`
- `BEGIN END$$;`

as three separate statements. This would result in the reported error, e.g.

```
$ psql -c 'DO $$ DECLARE A integer;'
ERROR:  unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$$ DECLARE A integer;"
LINE 1: DO $$ DECLARE A integer;
           ^
```

This is why you *must* specify your client driver/application when asking questions.

---

Another possibility with some clients is that it might treat `$` as an escaped query-parameter placeholder and replace it with a single `$` or try to substitute it for a server-side placeholder like `$1`. That's not what's happening here, though.

Answer (score 0):

DBeaver also gives this error when there is a SQL syntax error in the script.
In my case, it was a pair of mismatched parenthesis in a select calculated column.