# DBeaver not compiling a function that compiles using psql client

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dbeaver, dollar-quoting

I can compile the next function using psql client. However, DBeaver-ce returns the error

> SQL Error [42601]: Unterminated dollar quote started at position 0 in SQL $$;. Expected terminating $$".

Why?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION numOf_icd10cm_4_snomed(oldCode TEXT)
RETURNS integer
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS 
$$

-- This function returns the nunber of icd10cm codes matching oldCode in the table snomed2icd10

DECLARE
   quantity integer;  
BEGIN

   quantity := (select count(maptarget) 
             from 
                snomed2icd10
              where 
                 referencedcomponentid = oldCode
             );
    return quantity;

END;
$$;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$$](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634418/unterminated-dollar-quoted-string-at-or-near)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try enclosing the entire thing in a [DbVis SQL block](http://confluence.dbvis.com/display/UG100/Executing+Complex+Statements), using --/ and / to wrap the DDL (or DML), i.e.:

```
--/
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION numOf_icd10cm_4_snomed(oldCode TEXT)
RETURNS integer
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS 
$$

-- This function returns the nunber of icd10cm codes matching oldCode in the table snomed2icd10

DECLARE
   quantity integer;  
BEGIN

   quantity := (select count(maptarget) 
             from 
                snomed2icd10
              where 
                 referencedcomponentid = oldCode
             );
    return quantity;

END;
$$;
/
```